# QProcess outputs with delay threads' stdout/stderr of multithreaded application

Tags: linux, multithreading, qt, ubuntu, qprocess

My platform:

- Ubuntu 17.10 32-bit (Vbox VM)
- Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource)
- Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 32 bit

I am trying to invoke a multithreaded program (with arguments) using **QProcess**.start().

My program runs fine on terminal, i.e. periodically prints on stdout.

Using a TextEdit to log the stdout/stderr of the program I have connected QProcess **readyReadStandardOutput**/**Error** signals.

The stdout/stderr that comes from the main thread of the program is correctly shown on the TextEdit, the rest of the output (the one from all the other threads) is not shown.

**EDIT**

On the main thread an HTTP server is listening.

If a HTTP request is performed by browser at the url "127.0.0.1:32001" (port 32001 is hard coded in the QT code), when the HTTP request is received the program appends the HTTP packet and all the pending output from the other thread (moduleThread) to the TextEdit, so it could be a problem of flushing.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "http_server.h"

static pthread_t moduleThr;
static pthread_attr_t moduleThread_attr;
static bool one_second_elapsed;
static sem_t oneSecondSem;

void *moduleThread(void *arg0)
{
    bool one_second_elapsed_local;

    while (1)
    {
        sem_wait(&oneSecondSem);
        one_second_elapsed_local = one_second_elapsed;
        one_second_elapsed = false;
        sem_post(&oneSecondSem);

        if (one_second_elapsed_local)
            fprintf(stdout, "Hello world each second!\r\n");

        usleep(50000);
    }
}

static void oneSecElapsed(int signum)
{
    sem_wait(&oneSecondSem);
    one_second_elapsed = true;
    sem_post(&oneSecondSem);
}

static void TIMER_1sec_init(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct itimerval timer;

    /* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGALRM. */
    memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
    sa.sa_handler = &oneSecElapsed;
    sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

    /* Configure the timer to expire after 1 sec... */
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    /* ... and every 1 sec after that... */
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    /* Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is
    executing. */
    setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
}

/*
 *  ======== main ========
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *tcpport;

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "id = %s\r\n", argv[1]);
        fprintf(stdout, "tcpport = %s\r\n", argv[2]);
        tcpport = argv[2];
    }
    else
        exit(-1);

    sem_init(&oneSecondSem, 0, 1);
    one_second_elapsed = false;

    /* Create thread quadro manager */
    pthread_attr_init(&moduleThread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&moduleThread_attr, 2048);
    pthread_create(&moduleThr, &moduleThread_attr, moduleThread, NULL);

    TIMER_1sec_init();

    HTTPSERVER_init(tcpport);

    /* should never return */
    return (0);
}
```

**http_server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* memset() */
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "module.h"

typedef struct { char *name, *value; } header_t;
static header_t reqhdr[17] = { {"\0", "\0"} };

//#define PORT    "32001" /* Port to listen on */
#define BACKLOG 10  /* Passed to listen() */

static char *buf;
static char *method;    // "GET" or "POST"
static char *uri;       // "/index.html" things before '?'
static char *qs;        // "a=1&b=2"     things after  '?'
static char *prot;      // "HTTP/1.1"
static char *payload;     // for POST
static int   payload_size;

// get request header
char *request_header(const char* name)
{
    header_t *h = reqhdr;
    while(h->name) {
        if (strcmp(h->name, name) == 0) return h->value;
        h++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void handle(int newsock)
{
    //static int count = 0;
    /* recv(), send(), close() */
    int rcvd;

    buf = malloc(65535);
    rcvd=recv(newsock, buf, 65535, 0);

    if (rcvd<0)    // receive error
        fprintf(stderr,("recv() error\n"));
    else if (rcvd==0)    // receive socket closed
        fprintf(stderr,"Client disconnected unexpectedly.\n");
    else    // message received
    {
        buf[rcvd] = '\0';

        //fputs(buf, stdout);
        //fprintf(stdout, "count = %d\n", count);

        method = strtok(buf,  " \t\r\n");
        uri    = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        prot   = strtok(NULL, " \t\r\n"); 

        fprintf(stderr, "\x1b[32m + [%s] %s\x1b[0m\n", method, uri);

        if ((qs = strchr(uri, '?')))
        {
            *qs++ = '\0'; //split URI
        } else {
            qs = uri - 1; //use an empty string
        }

        header_t *h = reqhdr;
        char *t = (char *)reqhdr;
        char *t2;
        while(h < reqhdr+16) {
            char *k,*v;
            k = strtok(NULL, "\r\n: \t");
            if (!k)
                break;
            v = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
            while(*v && *v==' ')
                v++;
            h->name  = k;
            h->value = v;
            h++;
            fprintf(stderr, "[H] %s: %s\n", k, v);
            t = v + 1 + strlen(v);
            if (t[1] == '\r' && t[2] == '\n')
                break;
        }
        t+=2;
        t++; // now the *t shall be the beginning of user payload
        t2 = request_header("content-length"); // and the related header if there is  
        payload = t;
        payload_size = t2 ? atol(t2) : (rcvd-(t-buf));

        fprintf(stdout, "-- payload len = %d >", payload_size);
        fputs(payload, stdout);
        fprintf(stdout, "<\r\n");

        if (strcmp(method, "GET") == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "\nit's a GET!\r\n");
        }
        else if (strcmp(method, "POST") == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "\nit's a POST!\r\n");   
        }

        sprintf(buf, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
        send(newsock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
        close(newsock);
        free(buf);
    }
}

int HTTPSERVER_init(const char *tcpport)
{
    int sock;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int reuseaddr = 1; /* True */
    sigset_t sigset, oldset;

    sigfillset(&sigset);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, &oldset);

    /* Get the address info */
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, tcpport, &hints, &res) != 0) {
        perror("getaddrinfo");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Create the socket */
    sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Enable the socket to reuse the address */
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseaddr, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Bind to the address */
    if (bind(sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Listen */
    if (listen(sock, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    /* Main loop */
    while (1) {

        printf("waiting on accept\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        socklen_t size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
        int newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, &size);

        if (newsock == -1) {
            perror("accept");
        }
        else {
            printf("Got a connection from %s on port %d\n", 
                    inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr), htons(their_addr.sin_port));
            handle(newsock);
        }
    }

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out by @eyllanesc, the pending strings "Hello world each second!\r\n" come out eventually after several seconds.

The moduleThread shoud be a thread and not a different process: this is verified by commadn "ps aux" that shows only "../program/testApp test 32001".

Could any of you kindly give me a hint on what is going on here please?

Thanks for your time,

Francesco

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: absolutely right. done @eyllanesc. thank you for the feedback

Comment: Do not use a link to provide an [MCVE], in the future the link could be broken making your question unusable for future readers, please put the code as text, please read [ask]

Comment: the problem is that the impression of hello world is in another process, therefore QProcess does not detect that impression.

Comment: although I observe after a long time I observe the "Hello world each second!\r\n"

Comment: Why you say "Hello world..." is done by another process?  Is there a way to enable the detection of the output of moduleTread? Thanks for the feedback